# Assume that $G$ is abelian and $H \le G$. If $k=\{x \in G\mid x^2 \in H\}$ then prove that $k \le G$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Assume that $G$ is abelian and $H \le G$. If $k=\{x \in G \mid x^2 \in H\}$ then prove that $k \le G$.

I tried to use this rule: Assume $k$ is a subset of $G$. If for each $x,y\in k$ there is $xy\in k$ and $x^{-1}\in k$ then $k$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I managed to prove the closed property of $k$, but couldn't prove the inversion property.

For the closed property I wrote:
for each $x,y \in k$ then $x^2, y^2\in H$, and since $H$ is a subgroup and has the closed property then $x^2y^2 \in H$ thus $(xy)^2 \in H$ and finally $xy \in k$.

Also, I don't know how the abelian property can be used here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To show that $x^{-1} \in k$ is equivalent to showing that $(x^{-1})^2 \in H$.

Comment: Yes, but problem is , I didn't exactly know how to show that.

Comment: $(x^{-1})^2 = (x^2)^{-1}$, and $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

Since $H\le G$, we have $e\in H$, so $e=e^2\in H$, which implies $e\in k$. Hence $k\neq\varnothing$.

Since $k=\{\color{red}{x\in G}\mid x^2\in H\}$, we have $k\subseteq G$.

Now consider $x,y\in k$. Then $x^2,y^2\in H$, so we have

$$(xy^{-1})^2=x^2y^{-2}$$

(since $G$ is abelian), but $H\le G$, so $H$ is closed (and closed under taking inverses), meaning $x^2y^{-2}\in H$, so $xy^{-1}\in k$.

Hence $k\le G$.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted care to explain why?

Answer (score 3):

You are using abelian property of $G$  when you write $x^2 y^2 = xxyy\in H$ thus $(xy)(xy) = (xy)^2 \in H.$

In a nonabelian group $G'$, where commutativity does not hold, if $x, y \in G'$, then it is possible that $x^2y^2 = xxyy \neq xyxy = (xy)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ is a group homomorphism and $H_2 \le G_2$, then $\phi^{-1}(H_2) \le G_1$.

Apply this to $G_1=G_2=G$, $H_2=H$, and $\phi(x)=x^2$, which is a homomorphism because $G$ is abelian.